# How to make compiler know which overload of a function to call to avoid ambiguity?

Tags: c++, constructor, casting, operator-overloading, ambiguity

I have a code as below and I don't understand why exactly compiler can't infer the constructor to be used when instance of D class is created.
I have deleted both copy and move constructor so the only alternative would be to use A(Base&)

Is there are a way to tell compiler to use A(Base&) constructor, besides casting *this to Base&.

```
class Base {};

class A
{
    private:
    Base& m_b;
    public:

    A(Base& b) :m_b(b) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};

class D : public Base, public A
{
    public:
    D():A(*this){}

};

int main()
{  
    D();
}
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'D::D()':
main.cpp:17:16: error: call of overloaded 'A(D&)' is ambiguous
     D():A(*this){}
                ^
main.cpp:10:5: note: candidate: A::A(const A&) <deleted>
     A(const A&) = delete;
     ^
main.cpp:9:5: note: candidate: A::A(Base&)
     A(Base& b) :m_b(b) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a cast:

```
D():A(static_cast<Base&>(*this)){}
```

This will force the expression to have the type which matches your desired overload.

Simply deleting a function or c'tor doesn't remove it from the overloads set, which is why you see an ambiguity. It would only make the compiler consider the program as ill-formed if the function is ever *chosen* from all available overloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the pointer before dereferencing it:

```
D() :A(*(Base*)this) {}
```

or

```
D() :A(*static_cast<Base*>(this)) {}
```